# localtimestamp is always returning the same value

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

I have been recently porting a Perl application form Oracle to Postgres (my first time with Postgres) and I am stumped by a small issue which I was able to reduce to the following sample code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my @db_params = qw (dbi:Pg:host=127.0.0.1;database=test test test);

my $dbh = DBI->connect(@db_params, {AutoCommit => 0 } ) or die ;
while (1) {
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare_cached('SELECT localtimestamp ') or die;
    $sth->execute() or die;
    my $result = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
    print $result->[0][0] , "\n";
    sleep(5);
}
```

This outputs :

```
2011-11-27 16:46:25.94291
2011-11-27 16:46:25.94291
2011-11-27 16:46:25.94291
```

I am getting the same time stamp all the time unless I disconnect and reconnect to the database.

How can I make sure that ever time I select localtimestamp from the database I get the value corresponding to the time when the sql is executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are not using autocommit, you are always in the same transaction, and localtimestamp gets the timestamp at the start of that transaction in Postgres. I.e. you will need to create individual transactions for your queries, using `$dbh->begin_work` and `$dbh->commit`.

Comment: You're right! Strange I did not figure transactions worked differently between Oracle and Pg. The original code worked as expected in Oracle without having to commit the transaction!

Comment: That's true, Oracle behaves differently, but if you change the timestamp of a bunch of rows in one transaction, it makes more sense to me if they get all the same timestamp.

Comment: Everything that happens within a transaction is *supposed* to happen at the same time. PostgreSQL's handling of timestamps in transactions is logically more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Also take a look in the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) for the `statement_timestamp` and `clock_timestamp` functions.